# Valums file upload - onComplete

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm using the Valums file upload pluging, and having trouble with the onComplete method/trigger/event, whatever it's called... It just never triggers. Put a breakpoint there, never happened. This is my code:

```
jQuery('.btnUploader').each(function (index) {
    var uploader1 = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: jQuery('.btnUploader')[index], // The HTML element to turn into the uploader
        onSubmit: function () {
            var componentId = $(this).attr('element').id;
            var teamId = clbTeams.GetValue();
            uploader1.setParams({
                componentId: componentId,
                teamId: teamId
            });
        },
        onComplete: function (id, filename, responseJSON) {
            alert('test');
        },
        action: getUrl('ControllerUploadHandler', 'TeamStatusSubmit'), // Action method that will handle the upload
        multiple: false, // Single or Mutliple file selection
        allowedExtensions: ['docx', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'zip', 'ppt'] // File Type restrictions
    });
});
```

I believe, something's wrong with the function there and its parameters. Anybody's got a solution?

Comment: action: getUrl('ControllerUploadHandler', 'TeamStatusSubmit') What is getUrl? Yeap, looks like some local js function, but still, does it return proper value? Is server side ok? Valums uploader should get proper response from the server.

Comment: Have you attempted debug: true, in your params to see what errors you get?

Comment: getUrl comes with the valums example files for mvc somewhere... the problem is not with that method, the file gets uploaded, just the onComplete part never gets hit. I already went back to devexpress, and managed to make this work, but I'll get back later to the code just to see if there's a problem when `debug: true` is turend one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be ok. Look at response from server. Maybe some server error.